# Jenkins vs shell scripts

Tags: bash, redhat, automation, jenkins, shell-scripting

why would Jenkins get a different result from shell scripts(redhat 7) alone? I have shell scripts that run fine if I execute them from a terminal, however when I run the scripts from Jenkins they get different results
Jenkins 2.263.4

Comment: What kind of different result? Because in your terminal for starters you normally and by default  would  have a different and richer environment which in Jenkins you would need to explicitly configure

Comment: Compare which environment variables are set.  The `PATH` could be radically different, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of reasons that could happen, but the most common is because of Jenkins not using a "login shell" by default whereas your default local shell is a login shell. This means that it sources your `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or other login scripts are executed locally, but not when launching remotely.

There's a few different ways to make a login shell, but if you were using `bash` try this at the top of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

Alternatively, if you're missing an environment variable that would cause different behavior as well. Run `printenv` on your local shell, then run that as part of a Jenkins shell command, and compare to see if there's a variable that isn't getting defined.